# Trouble solving $\sqrt{x^2+12}-2x > 0$ by squaring both sides

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality

To solve the inequality $\sqrt{x^2+12}-2x > 0$ ,
at some point you would need to square both the sides and then the answer comes out to be $(-2,2)$; however, this is apparently wrong in the solution page of my textbook with the answer being $(-\infty,2)$.

Any help on this one?

Answer (score 2):

Adding $2x$ to both sides gives $$\sqrt{x^2+12}>2x$$So far, we haven't altered the inequality at all.

Now we want to square both sides. How does that affect the inequality? It's complicated. In fact, we have to do case work:

Case $1$: $x<0$. The inequality is true, since $\sqrt{y}\geq0$ for all $y\geq0$. And, $x^2+12\geq0$.

Case $2$: $x\geq0$. Squaring both sides doesn't change the sign of either, since both sides are positive, so since $y^2$ is monotonic on $\mathbb R^{\geq0}$, we have $x^2+12>2x$. From your work, you know that the solutions for this case are $(-2,2)\cap[0,\infty)=[0,2)$.

So, our answer is $(-\infty,0)\cup[0,2)=(-\infty,2)$.

Answer (score 0):

When you are asked to solve this type of inequalities, you must solve this system:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x^2+12\geq0
\\ x^2+12>4x^2
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
The first inequality holds for all $x$ in $R$, while the second for $X\geq0$, so we have:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x\geq0
\\ \forall x \in R
\\ -2<x<2
\end{matrix}\right.$$
But, if $x<0$ then the inequality holds, so the solutions are:
$$x<2$$

Comment: Why is the condition $2x\ge 0$ in the first part there? It doesn't make sense. Then suddenly at the end $x<0$ is introduced where the inequality always hold, making it clear that $2x \ge 0$ is coming out if thin air.

Comment: @lngix: yes, sorry. That was a typo. Corrected.

Comment: @Matteo Also, asking for upvotes is considered [in bad taste](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167155/comments-asking-for-upvotes-accepts)

Comment: $x=2$ is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

By continuity, the truth value of the inequation can only change where equality holds,

$$\sqrt{t^2+12}=2t,$$

solved by the only solution $t=2$ (due to the LHS we have $t>0$).

Taking arbitrary values on both sides, say $0$, and $4$, we have

$$\sqrt{0^2+12}>2\cdot0,$$ 
$$\sqrt{4^2+12}<2\cdot4$$

and the solution of the inequation is indeed $$x<2.$$